# What is the Regex for Only One @ Character?

Tags: php, regex, input, character

I am looking for a Regex to use in PHP in order to match one character; the `@` symbol.

For example, if I typed: `P@ssword` into an input, the Regex will match. If I typed `P@@ssword` into an input, the regex will not match.

Here is my PHP Code that I am using:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$conn=mssql_connect('d','dd','d');
mssql_select_db('d',$conn);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
}

    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
 if (preg_match("[\W]",$_POST["password"]))
  {
if (!preg_match("^[^@]*@[^@]*$",$_POST["password"]))
{
 header("location:logingbm.php");
} else {    
}
  }
if(!filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
    if ($_POST["username"])
 {
   if ($_POST["password"])
  {
        $result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM staffportal WHERE email='".$username."' AND
      password='".$password."'");
  if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $_SESSION['staff_logged_in'] = 1;
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }}}} else { 

    if ($_POST["password"])
  {
        $result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM staffportal WHERE email='".$username."' AND
      password='".$password."'");
  if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $_SESSION['staff_logged_in'] = 1;
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
  }}}}

  if(!isset($_SESSION['staff_logged_in'])) {
    header("location:logingbm.php");
    echo "<script>alert('Incorrect log-in information!');</script>";
  } else {
    header("location:staffportal.php");
  }
?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem like attempts and telling us where you are stuck instead of simply giving the community a list of requirements.

Comment: Honestly I'd forgo the regular expression and just iterate characters in the string.  If you hit a second `@` then you bail out with an error.  In this case, regex is using a sledgehammer to kill a fly.

Comment: How would I do that @cdhowie?

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this question since the OP ask a clear question, and has produced code.

Comment: The patterns need delimiters, example with slashes: `preg_match("/^[^@]*@[^@]*$/" ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the return value of [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

> Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

[**Example:**](http://ideone.com/L0NBba)

```
$count = preg_match_all('/@/', $password, $matches);
```

---

Non regex solution (based off of @cdhowie's comment):

```
$string = 'P@ssword';
$length = strlen($string);

$count = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    if($string[$i] === '@') {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

This works because you can [access characters of Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) as you would with normal arrays (`$var = 'foo'; $var[0] = 'f';`).

Comment: When i `echo` `$count`, it returns nothing. Can you explain to me how I would get the number of @ symbols out of the `$password` value?

Comment: @Kelsey, if you are not on PHP >= `5.4.0`, then `preg_match_all()` requires a 3rd parameter.  Try updating this to `$count = preg_match_all('/@/', $password, $matches);`.

Comment: When I echo `$match`, it only echos `Array`, how would it to echo the number rather than the word `Array`? Sorry, to lay all of my questions on you.

Comment: @Kelsey, in my example, `$matches` will be an array of matches (very useless to you, to see this you would do `print_r($matches);`). However, the return of `preg_match_all()`, which we set to `$count`, should equal the number of matches. `echo $count;` should work (I don't think it was before since you didn't have `$matches`, which was causing it to fail and return `FALSE`).

Comment: You can also just use `echo array_count_values(str_split($str))['@'];`.

Answer (score 2):

Other lightweight approaches...

**Without regex**

Just use `substr_count` (see [demo](http://ideone.com/9FKSzn))

```
<?php
$str1 = "pa@s@s";
$str2 = "pa@ss";
echo (substr_count($str1,"@")==1)?"beauty\n":"abject\n"; // abject
echo (substr_count($str2,"@")==1)?"beauty\n":"abject\n"; // beauty
```

**With regex**

EDIT: just saw that Sam wrote something equivalent.

If you want to use regex, you could use this fairly simple regex:

```
@
```

How? This code (see [demo](http://ideone.com/9FKSzn))

```
<?php
$str1 = "pa@s@s";
$str2 = "pa@ss";
$regex = "~@~";
echo (preg_match_all($regex,$str1,$m)==1)?"beauty\n":"abject\n"; // abject
echo (preg_match_all($regex,$str2,$m)==1)?"beauty\n":"abject\n"; // beauty
```

Answer (score 1):

This regexp will do what you want:

```
^[^@]*@[^@]*$
```

This matches any line that contains one and only one `@`.

### Explanation

- `^` matches the beginning of the line
- `[^@]*` matches everything before the `@`
- `@` matches the @ character
- `[^@]*` matches everything after the `@`
- `$` matches the end of the line

### Use

```
preg_match("#^[^@]*@[^@]*$#", $passwd); //Matches $passwd if it contains only one character
```

Comment: I have added the code I am using, to my question. Please take a look, because I am using the code you provided but it doesn't seem to be working. (It logs me in, instead of sending me back to the login screen.)

Comment: This is because you don't use preg_match correctly. You have to surround the regexp by a delimiter. In your case, you can use `preg_match("#^[^@]*@[^@]*$#",$_POST["password"])`

Comment: But I agree with @Sam, you shouldn't use a regex here. This slows down your code, and increases memory usage, for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, your pattern needs delimiters `/`, `#`, `~` or whatever you want (see the PHP doc for that and test yourself).

To be quickly sure that a string contains only one `@`, you can do that:

```
if (preg_match('~\A[^@]*@[^@]*\z~', $yourstr))
    echo 'There is one @';        
else
    echo 'There is more than one @ or zero @';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what your regex code means:

> If there is at least one non-word character in the string (`[\W]`), there must be exactly one at-sign (`@`).  There may be any number of any other characters before and after the at-sign: letters, digits, control characters, punctuation, anything.  Anything but `@`.

What I'm wondering is, are you trying to say there can be **not more than one** at-sign   (i.e. *zero* or *one*?)  That's pretty simple, conceptually; just get rid of the first regex check (`"[\W]"`) and change the second regex to this:

```
"^[^@]*(?:@[^@]*)?$"
```

In other words:

> Start by consuming *not at-signs* you see.  If you see a `@`, go ahead and consume it, then resume matching whatever *not at-signs* remain.  If that doesn't leave you at the end of the string, it can only mean there were more than one `@`.  Abandon the attempt immediately and report a failed match.

Of course, this still leaves you with the problem of which other characters you want to allow.  I'm pretty sure `[^@]*` is not what you want.

Also, `"[\W]"` may be working as you intended, but it's only by accident.  You could have written it `"/\W/"` or `"~\W~"` `"(\W)"` and it would work just the same.  You may have meant those square brackets to form a character class, but they're not even part of the regex; they're the regex *delimiters*.

So why did it work, you ask?  `\W` is a predefined character class, equivalent to `[^\w]`.  You *can* use it inside a regular character class, but it works fine on its own.